# subprocess status never change at the end of process

Tags: python, process

I have a simple python code that prints a line.

```
# in the simple_print.py
print "  in the simple_print.py   "
```

in another file i use **subprocess.Popen** to execute this code:

```
import psutil, subprocess

cmd = "python simple_print.py"
P = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
psProcess = psutil.Process(pid=P.pid)

print "status: ", psProcess.status
```

The status is always **running**. Whats wrong? since it should be finished or terminated.
Thanks all.

Comment: Why are you running a Python script using `subprocess` rather than simply importing it & calling its `main()` function? Or is this just a simplified example to help you understand how to use `subprocess`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never wait for it to finish, your current calling process will never know what your customer process did, try a `P.wait()` before printing that status.